# Split string C++ by '\'

Tags: c++, c

I'm trying to split a path from Windows by '' , but when I'm running my program crashes.
Here's a small example:

```
char*s = "C:\\windows\\system32\\calc.exe";
char*pch;
pch = strtok(s,"\\");
while(pch!=NULL){
 printf("%s\n",pch);
 pch = strtok(NULL,"\\");
}
```

I can make a search manually, but I think it's easier way than that.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtok _"Notes
This function is destructive: it writes the '\0' characters in the elements of the string str. In particular, a string literal cannot be used as the first argument of strtok."_ Enable compiler warnings and your compiler will show you such problems.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/begin
Should do everything

Comment: Do not tag both C and C++. Tag only the language you are using. Do not use `strtok` on string literals (including pointers that point to string literals or parts of them). To use `strtok` on a string defined by a literal, initialize an array with it, as in `char s[] = "C:\\windows\\system32\\calc.exe";`. In future questions, avoid giving an isolated excerpt; prepare a [mre]. Turn on warnings in your compiler and pay attention to them. Preferably, set your compiler to treat warnings as errors.

Comment: It worked when compiled with Digital Mars.

Comment: @user10191234 The Digital Mars compiler allows you to modify **string literals**?

Comment: Oddly enough yes, even without warnings.

Comment: That's undefined behavior, no diagnostic required. Your compiler is allowed to compile it without errors or warnings. But most compilers will give you a warning. You should use such a compiler.

Comment: Since you tagged as C++, use the `std::string` type for characters.  You can then use `std::string::find` to get the starting or ending position and `std::string::substr` to extract the substring.

Comment: Since you tagged as C++, an alternative is to use `std::istringstream` and use the `std::getline` (with delimiter) to *read* the substring from the string stream.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Using c++ http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/99fc6f4339912308 or indeed std::filesystem:  http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/11f33ce6d0ea8b74

Comment: @ThomasSablik Embarcadero's compiler gives a warning `conversion from string literal to 'char *' is deprecated` but the program ran.

Comment: @user10191234 _"No diagnostic required"_ means this code is wrong but the compiler is not required to report this error or break the compilation process. An optional warning helps the developer to find these errors. Therefore you should handle warnings as errors if possible.

Comment: You tagged C language, but say you are using C++.  Which language (update your tags)?  They are different languages.  For example, C++ has `std::string` type, C has only character arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a mutable string. A string literal is immutable. Trying to change a string literal will result in undefined behavior. Instead of `char *s = "C:\\windows\\system32\\calc.exe";` (pointer to string literal) you can simply use a array of chars `char s[] = "C:\\windows\\system32\\calc.exe";`. This will copy the string literal into a mutable array.

Answer (score 0):

The only problem is that you have to use `char s[]` insead of `char* s`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    char s[] = "C:\\windows\\system32\\calc.exe";
    char * pch;
    pch = strtok (s,"\\");
    while (pch != NULL) {
        printf ("%s\n",pch);
        pch = strtok (NULL, "\\");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I prefer not to use `strtok` because it can only access by `char*`.

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
 
template <class Container>
void split(const std::string& str, Container& cont, char delim = '\\')
{
    std::stringstream ss(str);
    std::string token;
    while (std::getline(ss, token, delim)) {
        cont.push_back(token);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

After I read all the comments, I realized that I can make a copy of that `path` and replace all '\' with another character, like '*', then you can use `strtok(modifiedCopy,"*")` function without any problem. Anyway, thanks to everyone in the comments section.

Comment: You don't need to modify the string. You only need a mutable string. A string literal is immutable. Trying to change it will result in undefined behavior. Instead of `char*s = "C:\\windows\\system32\\calc.exe";` you can simply `char s[] = "C:\\windows\\system32\\calc.exe";`. This will copy the string literal into a mutable array.

Comment: @ThomasSablik I tried your advice and it worked. Answer the question in order to mark the correct answer, thanks